# R: Efficiently determining which slices of one array occur in a second

Tags: r, arrays

I have two three-dimensional arrays in R, and wish to identify which slices of `array1` occur in `array2`.

With one-dimensional vectors, I can go

```r
vector1 <- 1:5
vector2 <- 2:4
vector1 %in% vector2
```

But with three dimensional arrays, the best I can come up with is

```r
array1 <- array(rep(1:5, each=4), dim=c(2, 2, 5))
array2 <- array(rep(2:4, each=4), dim=c(2, 2, 3))
apply(array1, 3, function (x) {
      any(apply(array2, 3, identical, x))
})
```

As I'm going to be making this comparison many millions of times on matrices of modest size, this inefficient comparision becomes the rate-limiting step.  Does a function exist that will allow a more efficient implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` to *determining which slices of one array occur in a second*:

```
duplicated(array(c(array2, array1), c(dim(array1)[1:2], dim(array1)[3]
   +dim(array2)[3])), MARGIN=3)[-seq_len(dim(array2)[3])]
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

But this will work only if you don't have duplicated already in `array1`.

Comment: Orders of magnitude faster and no external libraries required – many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `outer` which compares every matrix with every other matrix in both of them hence, I am not too confident about it's efficiency here.

```
fn <- function(x, y) all(array1[, , x] == array2[, , y])

apply(outer(seq_len(dim(array1)[3]),seq_len(dim(array2)[3]), Vectorize(fn)), 1, any)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```